# Important examples of degenerate quantum error correcting codes

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-error-correction

A degenerate quantum error correcting code is one in which distinct error operators (e.g. $E_1$ and $E_2$) apply the same transformation to the code's logical states (i.e. $E_1|\psi_L\rangle = E_2|\psi_L\rangle$ for $|\psi_L\rangle$ in the code space). These aren't too uncommon; even the Shor code is degenerate ($Z_1$ and $Z_2$ have the same action on the code space, for example).

In Nielsen and Chuang's book on quantum information, they state

"In some sense [degenerate codes] are able to ‘pack more information in’ than are classical codes, because distinct errors do not necessarily have to take the code space to orthogonal spaces, and it is possible (though has not yet been shown) that this extra ability may lead to degenerate codes that can store quantum information more efficiently than any non-degenerate code."

Has this statement since been shown to be true or false? Are there any known degenerate codes that violate the Hamming bound (which is trivial to derive for non-degenerate codes)?

Answer (score -2):

degenerate quantum error-correcting codes have been shown to offer advantages in certain scenarios and can outperform non-degenerate codes in terms of efficiency. However, they still adhere to fundamental limitations, such as the Hamming bound, governing the number of correctable errors.

Comment: this doesn't seem to actually answer the question